# Verifying a variable using case statement

Tags: bash, shell, case

If I have a script (bash shell) and want to check to see if the argument passed is within a range of numbers, how would I do this using case statements? For instance, my script will perform a series of commands, only if the argument entered is numbers 10-20, otherwise an error message is returned. I am able to do this with If statements but would like to know how to with case statements. I've read other pages, but It doesn't make sense to do:

```
case $1 in
10
*command executed
11
*command executed
etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
if (($1 >= 10 && $1 <=20)); then
    echo "Correct range"
else
    echo >&2 "Incorrect range"
fi
```

I use [bash arithmetic](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr). Using `case` statement here seems a bit inefficient.

If you insist to do it whit `case` :

```
case $1 in
    1[0-9]|20) echo "Correct range" ;;
    *) echo >&2 "Incorrect range" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use square brackets to indicate a list of possible values:

```
case $1 in
1[0-9]|20)
  echo "All is well. I will run the command."
  ;;
*)
  echo "All is not well! You are a fool to tell me such a number!"
  ;;
esac
```

See more about case statements [in the Bash Beginner's Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)

Answer (score 1):

using `$((...))` maybe useful :

```
case 1 in
  $(($1 >= 10 && $1 < 20))) echo '10-19';;
  $(($1 >= 20 && $1 < 30))) echo '20-29';;
  $(($1 >= 30 && $1 < 40))) echo '30-39';;
esac
```